# Trying to have the registration errors display block when error happens

Tags: javascript, css, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make certain 'divs' display block when errors happen when an individual goes to register in my app. I am using javascript but when I run my functions it is not working.

I am using javascript

Here is my js

```
    const auth = firebase.auth(); 

    const promise =  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email , password);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

    var errorCode = e.message;
    var emailExists = document.querySelector('.error-message-email');
    var passwordWeak = document.querySelector('.error-message-password-weak');

    if (errorCode === 'The email address is already in use by another account.') {
        emailExists.style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (errorCode === 'auth/weak-password') {
        passwordWeak.style.display = 'block'
    }
```

I am looking at the documentation but it seems to not capture what I am doing in firebase and it only logs in the console the errors and not having the errors messages display block

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying CSS via JavaScript, try toggling a class `.hidden`. The `hidden` CSS rule should be `display:none;`. In your HTML, set your `div`'s to include the `hidden` class.

As you wish, use JavaScript's `.classList.add` and `.remove`, or `.toggle` to show them.

As for why it's not working as is, it's probably because you have rules at the `id` (`#`) level which override the class rules.